# General questions about JHipster

Tags: architecture, jhipster

I am thinking about starting a project using jhipster but I still have a question remaining about the approach.
Jhipster is generating code, ok.
- Is it better to generate a project and then never use jhipster again ?
- or using the approach coding, using jhipster to edit entities, code again, jhipster, coding etc... ?

What is the best thing to do and what is your experience about it?

Answer (score 3):

Actually that's up to you. As you said you can just generate the project and "never use jhipster again". You'll have the project skeleton and most things you need, and will be able to manually generate all your entities/controllers ...

However I would not advise doing that. Jhipster has a lot of modules you can use and it helps you building a clean app, putting a lot of good practises in place for you. The community around it is really active and the project has updates regularly, so that your project may follow the latest technologies available.

A little trick when you start working with jhipster : use git and commit your modifications regularly (It is mentioned in most tutorials), you'll be able to revert them easily.

This is my point of view about the project but you can do pretty much every kind of app with Jhipster. Experience will help you determine if molding Jhipster default architecture to meet your expectations might be unrelevant.

Have a look at the video tutorials to see how people use Jhipster : [Jhipster official website](https://jhipster.github.io/video-tutorial/)

Hope this helps ! Don't hesitate to comment if an edit is needed for more details.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It helps to have feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at the early stage of a JHipster generated monolith Angular2/Spring/DB application.  I'm trying to understand what parts of the code should i leave to jhipster and what parts I should customize.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to regenerate all the entities again and rebuild my project without overwriting any logic.  But I'm not sure if that is possible or I haven't figure out yet how to achieve that.

What I'm saying is that I'd be building on the generated code, rather than replacing it.

For the client side, the generate code is being kept and restricted to the admin We are building a separate UI.

We are just now adding logic to the server and only now giving proper consideration to the the following:

- use of DTO
- where to put the business logic
- is it possible to add business logic as described above - seperate from JHipster code.. if that is desireable.

There are my thoughts.
Be very happy to hear comments back on this.

Kind regards,
Fergal.

Answer (score 0):

A way to be 'safe' is to use git. Use a master and develop branch (and ideally git flow). After generating your project in the develop branch, create a branch - something like 'original' - and checkout that branch whenever you want to do some JHipster magic. Checkout the develop branch and cherry pick the changes from the 'original' branch. This way you can change whatever you want in the develop branch.